# Filling Extjs Combobox with static data

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have in my base class a combobox, where I only configure the "fields" property. Like this:

```
items: [
      comboText = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
                width: 150,
                padding: '0 20 0 0',
                displayField: 'label',
                store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
                    fields: [
                        {type: 'string', name: 'label'},
                        {type: 'string', name: 'fieldName'}
                    ]
                })
            }),
...]
```

How can I pass only the data property to this combo ?
I tried the code below but does not work:

```
comboTest.store.loadData(value);
```

where value contains an array like this:

```
 [
    {"label":"First name", "fieldName":"firstname"},
    {"label":"Birth date", "fieldName":"birthdate"}
 ]
```

No errors, but the combobox opens nothing.

Answer (score 10):

I got this to work using:

```
   xtype:'combo',
   fieldLabel:'Division',
   name:'division',
   valueField: 'division',
   queryMode:'local',
   store:['A','B','C'],
   displayField:'division',
   autoSelect:true,
   forceSelection:true
```

I know this question is really old, but just in case anyone comes looking for an answer that works out of the box; for me this was it.

Comment: I like this solution for its simplicity. A reference to the API manual where this is described: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-store Look for the store config.

Answer (score 9):

Try this config:

```
       xtype:'combo',
       fieldLabel:'Division',
       name:'division',
       queryMode:'local',
       store:['A','B','C'],
       displayField:'division',
       autoSelect:true,
       forceSelection:true
```

Another Alternative is listed right in the [docs of the ComboBox](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox):

```
    // The data store containing the list of states
    var states = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        fields: ['abbr', 'name'],
        data : [
            {"abbr":"AL", "name":"Alabama"},
            {"abbr":"AK", "name":"Alaska"},
            {"abbr":"AZ", "name":"Arizona"}
            //...
        ]
    });

    // Create the combo box, attached to the states data store
    Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
        fieldLabel: 'Choose State',
        store: states,
        queryMode: 'local',
        displayField: 'name',
        valueField: 'abbr',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

`valueField` is mandatory for `combobox`.  Try setting the `valueField` in your combobox.

Answer (score 0):

It works:

```
{
    name: 'sample',
    xtype: 'combobox',
    allowBlank: false,
    emptyText: 'select ...',
    queryMode: 'local',
    itemId: 'sample',
    id: 'sample',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'name',
    forceSelection:true,
    store: ['B','C', 'A'],
    typeAhead: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of using loadData();

```
comboTest.store.loadData(value);
```

use loadRawData();

```
comboTest.store.loadRawData(value);
```

If confusion try ths [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2nam)